# Appending to a TextField when the user has finished editing has no effect

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a View which is comprised of rows in a List.

I want to add the suffix "kg" to each TextField when the user has finished editing. Here is a minimal example of my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct minworkoutview: View {
    @State private var textFieldInputs: [String] = Array(repeating: "", count: 5)
    @State private var weightEntries = [20, 20, 20, 20, 20]
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<5, id: \.self) { index in
                TextField("Enter Weight", text: $textFieldInputs[index], onCommit: {
                    let weightString = textFieldInputs[index].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).replacingOccurrences(of: " kg", with: "")
                    if let newWeight = Double(weightString) {
                        weightEntries[index] = Int(newWeight * 1000)
                        textFieldInputs[index] = "\(newWeight) kg"
                        
                        print("\(weightEntries[index])")
                        
                    }
                    
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct minworkoutview_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        minworkoutview()
    }
}
```

There are multiple TextFields, and the `weightEntries` array seems to be populating correctly (as seen in the print statement). Why isn't the textfield adding "kg" to the end of the text? It should be using `$textFieldInputs` as its data source, so why doesn't it change when `onCommit` is called?

Comment: Unrelated to your question: you are already  replacing whitespace, so use „kg“ not „ kg“ in your .replacingOccurrences or you will miss cases that you probably want to catch.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to work with Measurement and a formatter?

Comment: Yes to both I guess

Comment: @JoakimDanielson But it's really weird that the change to `textFieldInputs` is not reflected in UI. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Maybe because when you are updating the array in `onCommit` it doesn’t trigger a ui update.

Comment: You have to use some hack to do it with `Binding` instead. State changes work different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    textFieldInputs[index] = "\(newWeight) kg"
}
```

Change textFieldInput deley